# JSON parse fails when there are regular expressions

Tags: json, mongodb, json.net

I am trying to parse a mongodb query in json to dictionary and the JObject.Parse throws exception.

The JSON string is something like below

```
{ vendor: "xyx", product: { $in : [ /prod1/i, /prod2/i, /prod3/i ] } }
```

The exception is message is

> Error parsing comment. Expected: *, got p. Path 'product.$in', line 1, position 50.

Answer (score 1):

JSON doesn't have support for regular expressions but you could change your JSON string to use the [`$regex`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) query operator syntax instead:

```
{ vendor: "xyx", product: { $in: [
    {$regex: "prod1", $options: "i"},
    {$regex: "prod2", $options: "i"},
    {$regex: "prod3", $options: "i"} 
] } }
```

All in one string, of course.  And to be valid JSON, the keys all need to be quoted too, but `JObject.Parse` may allow them to be omitted as it doesn't sound like that part was giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't mean to say JSON, but rather MongoDB, no?

For MongoDB queries, you need to do this:

```
 { vendor: "xyx", product: { $in : [ Pattern.compile(/prod1/i),  Pattern.compile(/prod2/i),  Pattern.compile(/prod3/i) ] } }
```